# Please can someone explain why im getting an error message below?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$check_day = "select * from timetable where day ='$day'";
$run = mysql_query($check_day);
if(mysql_num_rows($run) > 0) {
  echo "<script>alert('day $day already exists in our database, please try another one!')</script>";
  exit();
}

$query = "insert into timetable (classes, courses, lecturers, time, room, day) values ('$classes','$courses','$lecturers','$time','$room','$day')";
if (mysql_query($query)) {
  echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!')</script>";
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! ***SQL Injection!*** *It's not just for breakfast any more!*

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @felixN your code can be hacked with SQL Injection, do not write code this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: @JohnConde What is the reserved word? `time` and `day` are keywords, but not reserved.

Comment: Can you explain why we don't know what that error message is?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
    /* As I read all the previous comments and find out that you are using old SQL query. which is a bad practice. */

    # Note: Please read what is mysqli, why we use mysqli

    # I have correct your query 



 // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


      $check_day = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day ='".$day."'";

    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$check_day);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run) >0) {

        echo "<script>alert('day $day already exists in our database, please try another one!')</script>";
            exit();
    }else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO timetable (`classes`, `courses`, `lecturers`, `time`, `room`, `day`) VALUES ('".$classes."','".$courses."','".$lecturers."','".$time."','".$room."','".$day."')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                echo "<script>alert('Registration Successful!')</script>";
    }

    }
```

## I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli its more secure and better.

First connect: `$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');`

Next we gonna make our query:

```
$query = "insert into timetable (classes, courses, lecturers, time, room, day) values ('$classes','$courses','$lecturers','$time','$room','$day')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Now your query is added, you can provide extra actions:

```
//Your extra code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using outdated PHP/MySQL functions.

use the new `mysqli_*` functions as they are more secure and updated.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp